# Read csv and split on semicolon

Tags: c++, string, csv

I have to read in values separated by ";" from a csv file...e.g

```
2039213;Hans;Meier;12.20.1943;2.4;
4039293;Jim;Raynor;31.12.2011;3.0;

int;char[];char[];char[],float
```

how can I split one line into the words using not string , just char[] ?
and then I have to put those splitted values into a struct, ok thats not too hard I think but how do I split values ?
my code:

```
struct Studentendaten {
    int matrnr;
    string name;
    string vorname;
    string datum;
    float note;
};
Studentendaten stud;
array<Studentendaten,100> studArray ;   


  if (pos != -1) 
  {

      sub1 = sub.substr(0,pos);               
      sub2  = sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
      sub3  = sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
      sub4  =sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
      sub5  =sub.substr(pos+1,pos);           
      stud.matrnr = std::to_string(sub1);
      stud.name = sub2;
      stud.vorname = sub3;
      stud.datum = sub4;
      stud.note = float(sub5);
  }

  if (ch == '\n') 
  {
      stud = {matrn,name,vorname,datum,note};
      studArray[i] = stud;
      i++;
  }
```

I have also the problem conversion from string into int and from string into float doesnt work, no matter what function I apply to it...
it often says :

```
dateiLesen.cc:54:19: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
```

or

```
 dateiLesen.cc:58:27: error: invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'float'
```

furthermore, I dont know what the  problem with my struct is:

```
 dateiLesen.cc:13:9: note: main()::Studentendaten& main()::Studentendaten::operator=(const main()::Studentendaten&)
  struct Studentendaten {
 dateiLesen.cc:13:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer  list>' to 'const main()::Studentendaten&'
dateiLesen.cc:13:9: note: main()::Studentendaten& main()::Studentendaten::operator=(main()::Studentendaten&&)
dateiLesen.cc:13:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'main()::Studentendaten&&'
```

Comment: You should fix your compiler errors *first* before trying to add any additional functionality.

Comment: for make I set:g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o "%e" "%f" and for compiler I set: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c "%f"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try and tackle those compile errors

`dateiLesen.cc:54:19: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'`

You're not including the header that defines std::to_string, so the compiler has no idea what it is.  [ hint: try google! ]

`dateiLesen.cc:58:27: error: invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'float'`

You can't cast a string into a float directly.  You'll need to use something like `boost::lexical_cast`